# AutoHotKey. Hotstrings and Auto-replace not working in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, hotkeys, autohotkey

Is it any possibility to persist work of Hotstrings in Visual Studio 2008.

For instance, I want to get following results: 
"ras" => replace to runat="server"

I use following script, which work in another application, except VS 2008.

::ras::runat="server"

Comment: I was able to use that hotstring in VS2008.
Is it possible that its not getting loaded due to other variables in the AHK script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running under the same account?

What about the solution posted over here:
[Why is visual studio catching key events before autohotkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890351/why-is-visual-studio-catching-key-events-before-autohotkey)

Comment: Answer from given link:

Either of the following solved the problem:
 - Running both vs and ahk as the current user
 - Compiling the script and running both vs and the compiled app as administrator