# Auto Hot key not working in application but working outside

Tags: node.js, electron, autohotkey

I have an electron app in which i am using Auto Hot key.I want to disable ALT+F4  for that i have written following script

```
!F4::Return
```

After execution of this script i am still able to close my electron app using Alt+F4 but for other application like for Notepad,folder etc script is working fine.

**For reference:** https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/AutoHotkey.htm

Comment: Might be because of privileges, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890351/why-is-visual-studio-catching-key-events-before-autohotkey/1905257#1905257

Answer (score 1):

**This disabled <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd> for all windows with "- Notepad" in the title**

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2     ; All #If statements match anywhere in title

#IfWinActive - Notepad
!F4::return
#IfWinActive
```

Replace `- Notepad` with the title of your Electron app's window

Answer (score 0):

I think your probably better off setting `closable: false` in your browser window options so that the electron window won't close and the other windows won't close.

[All browser window options](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions)