# Disabling ALT menu bar activation with AutoHotKey not working on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8.1, autohotkey

I've tried using `~LAlt Up:: return` in my AutoHotKey script.

But to no avail the menu bar still gains focus when I lift the key up.

Why does this trick work on other systems but not mine?

Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Might be because of privileges, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890351/why-is-visual-studio-catching-key-events-before-autohotkey/1905257#1905257

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/1336894/456981

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
LAlt up::
If (A_PriorKey = "LAlt") ;  If LAlt was pressed alone
    return ; do nothing
return

; In this case its necessary to define a custom combination by using "LAlt &" or "<!" 
; to avoid that LAlt loses its original function as a modifier key:

<!F4:: Send {Alt Down}{F4}{Alt Up} ; <! means LAlt
```

**EDIT:**

**This works in AHK v1.1.28+** without disabling Alt + click or wheel:

```
~LAlt::Send {Blind}{vkE8}
```

Comment: I am finding that this also disables Alt + click or wheel. These should work with just Alt down though, and have no connection to Alt up. Why then?

Comment: See EDIT in this answer.